# How to increase Service name: GPU (ALL REGION) quota limit in Compute Engine?

Tags: virtual-machines, google-compute-engine, quota, gpu

I requested 2 times for GPU all region service quota from 0 to 1 but not got accepted so ,I want a way to increase this limit.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Server Fault community can do nothing with such issues. You should reach Google Cloud to solve this issue.

I assume that you've got an email like this:

> Unfortunately, we are unable to grant you additional quota at this
> time. If this is a new project please wait 48h until you resubmit the
> request or until your Billing account has additional history.
>
> Your Sales Rep is a good Escalation Path for these requests, and we
> highly recommend you to reach out to them.
>
> If you have any further questions, please reply to this thread or feel
> free to reach out to us at gc-team@google.com.

**To solve this issue** you can try steps below:

- Try to work for a while with current quotas, if it possible for your use case, to get some history on your account and after that [request an increase in quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota).
- Try to split desired increase in quota into some steps that could be approved like 2 -> 4 -> 8 and so on
- Try to reach [Google Sales Team](https://cloud.google.com/contact).
- Try to reply again to `gc-team@google.com` but provide some arguments to clarify your request.

In addition, you're dealing with a credit situation. Is your credit good enough to justify a cloud vendor allowing access to resources that you pay for later? Review the credit card that you posted to your billing account. Does it only have $10.00 in credit available or are you using a corporate debit card? Are you a hobbyist or a business? How long has your account been open? These are factors that companies might consider in granting a credit line increase.

**EDIT**

You're not able to change quota while using [90-day, $300 Free Trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial). Have a look at the documentation:

> Program coverage:
>
> - You can't add GPUs to your VM instances.
> - You can't request a quota increase. For an overview of Compute Engine quotas, see [Resource quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas).

and

> To perform any of the actions in the list above, you must [upgrade to
> a paid account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade).

Comment: First thanks for your answer, can you please tell me that bill generate by using services of GPU(all region) will pay from where ? Either from free trial( 300$) or from my main account ?

Comment: I updated my answer. Please accept/upvote if it was useful for you.